# How can I improve how I read XML from Socket

Tags: java, xml, sockets

I am working on a Java client that connects to a server via socket and sends/receives XML messages. I know what the schema of the messages will be. I have it working currently, but it feels messy and I haven't tested it yet to see how it handles multiple XMLs sent from the server at once.

Here is the code:

```
  private static BufferedReader socketIn;
  private static PrintWriter socketOut;
  private static final String SERVICES_FILE = "/etc/services";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = getServicePortByName("Service1", "tcp");
    try {
      logger.info("Creating socket port with ip: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() + " and port: " + port);
      Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port);
      socketOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

      String message = createMessageXML("LOGIN");
      socketOut.println(message);

      socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      StringBuilder inputLine = new StringBuilder();
      String tmp;

      while (true) {
      //loop to keep listening/parsing
        while(socketIn.ready()) {
          tmp = socketIn.readLine();
          inputLine.append(tmp);
        }
        if(inputLine.length() > 0) {
          parseReceivedMessage(inputLine.toString());
        }
        inputLine.replace(0, inputLine.length(), "");
      }

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
```

the parseReceivedMessage method just takes in a String and converts it to a Document object. My question is, is there a better or cleaner way to do this instead of using a StringBuilder? I originally wanted to pass an InputStream to the DOM builder parse method.
I saw some examples making use of ByteArray streams, but I had some issues with those. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: What is the actual format of the protocol you are trying to implement?  Since this is apparently not a protocol of your making, do you have any documentation on the formatting of the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you design a framing protocol around your XML messages.  Prefix each XML message with a length value that specifies how many bytes are being transmitted, then send the XML itself (in bytes, not characters).  The receiver can then read the length, then read the specified number of bytes and pass them to the XML parser, then read the next length, and so on.  For example:

```
  private static DataInputStream socketIn;
  private static DataOutputStream socketOut;
  private static final String SERVICES_FILE = "/etc/services";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = getServicePortByName("Service1", "tcp");
    try {
      logger.info("Creating socket port with ip: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() + " and port: " + port);
      Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port);
      socketIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
      socketOut = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));

      byte[] message = createMessageXML("LOGIN");
      socketOut.writeInt(message.length());
      socketOut.write(message, 0, message.length());

      int len = socketIn.readInt();
      if (len > 0)
      {
          message = new byte[len];
          socketIn.readFully(message);
          parseReceivedMessage(message);
      }

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would, but I don't have control over the XML messages being sent to me. However, the messages will always follow the same format and be the same length. Could I just read a fixed amount of bytes every time?

Comment: That information should have been stated in your question. In that case, I would not rely on the messages always being the same length, since XML is variable-length, and the messages may be modified in the future. How are the messages delimited from each other? Based on your code, I assume the XML itself never has line breaks in it, and then a line break appears after the root element's closing tag, is that right? Is there a prolog on each message? If so, it has a line break after it, before the root element's opening tag.

Comment: If there is no obvious delimiter between each message, you will have to continuously read raw bytes into a rolling buffer and just keep scanning it for each message's closing tag, removing complete messages from the buffer as you process them. In fact, even with an obvious delimiter, you will likely end up having to go this approach anyway, scanning the buffer for the delimiter instead.

Comment: From your example above, what about modifying it so I continuously ready line-by-line until I reach the opening tag of the section I care about and stop once I have reached the closing tag?

Comment: that would only work if there are line breaks in the XML. But you could read using fixed-length buffers, putting each one into a continuous buffer, and then scan that for the opening/closing tags as needed.

Comment: Another thing to consider is using a SAX-based XML parser that supports a push model. Then you can push a custom opening tag it it, and then just keep pushing socket data into it, and let it notify you when it detects completed XML elements. This is how I usually handle streaming XML messages in other programming languages (I don't do much with Java nowadays).

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted by using an XMLStreamReader and checking stream events for start and end elements I am interested in. This way I can ignore the rest of the XML and still parse if multiple xml messages are sent back to back.

Answer (score 1):

`ready()` is not a valid test for end of message. Get rid of that and the `StringBuilder` and the `readLine()` calls altogether and just pass the input stream directly to the DOM parser.

Comment: I tried that but it just hangs on the .parse(inputstream) call.

Comment: Then a complete XML document isn't being sent.

Comment: but if I convert the stream to a string and pass that into the parser, it works fine. is it because it hangs until the stream the closed?

Comment: I don't think so. The usual problem with DOM parsers is that they close the stream when you don't necessarily want them to: in other words they know the end of the document.

Comment: It's possible that your DOM parser is blocking trying to retrieve a schema mentioned in your document, if there is one. You may need to install the schema locally and set an `EntityResolver` on the parser.

Comment: Would that work if the received messages don't have a public header specified? The examples I see of the EntityResolver all seem to check if the publicID matches what is specified in the message